# Determine if a cucumber scenario has pending steps

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I would like to retrieve the scenario state in the "After" scenario hook. I noticed that the .failed? method does not consider pending steps as failed steps.

So How can I determine that a scenario did not execute completely, because it failed OR because some steps were not implemented/defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use status method. The default value of status is `:skipped`, the failed one is `:failed` and the passed step is `:passed`. So you can write something like this:

```
do sth if step.status != :passed
```

Also, if you use `!step.passed?` it does the same thing because it only checks for the `:passed` status.

- http://cukes.info/api/cucumber/ruby/yardoc/Cucumber/Ast/Scenario.html#failed%3F-instance_method

On that subject, you can also take a look at this post about demoing your feature specs to your customers: http://multifaceted.io/2013/demo-feature-tests/

Comment: Ok, but since the AfterStep hook is not called, I need to use the After scenario hook and loop over all the steps right? But I dońt Know how can I access the steps when the scenario is an outline (the scenario parameter received has no "steps" method)

Comment: When I try to access the "steps" method, I get the following error : private method `steps' called for #<Cucumber::Ast::ScenarioOutline:0x007ff2cc374b70> (NoMethodError)
      /Users/...features/support/hooks.rb:126:in `After'

Comment: The 2nd link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

LiohAu, you can use the 'status' method on a scenario itself rather than on individual steps. Try this: In hooks, add

```
After do |scenario|
  p scenario.status
end
```

This will give the statuses as follows:
Any step not implemented / defined, it'll give you :undefined
Scenario fails (when all steps are defined) :failed
Scenario passes :passed

Using the same hook, it'll give you the status for scenario outline, but for each example row (since for each example row, it is an individual scenario). So if at all you want the result of an entire outline, you'll need to capture result for all example rows and compute the final result accordingly.

Hope this helps.